# How to handle multiple changing ID's for a single person

Tags: data-warehouse, erwin

I have a company with a single party table containing Member ID(the primary key), Subscriber ID, Member Sequence ID, Legacy ID, and a myriad of other identifiers from random source systems. Because they all live in a single table, it's not possible to capture the full scope of a person as they could have multiple unique ID's in this table (they can be assigned a new member ID for various reasons).

They can get also get changes to their subscriber ID (or any other ID) as well, with no other changes. I've tried to figure out the best way to track a person, but am a bit lost.

I've created a new table, DIM_PERSON that contains some attributes. I've linked this to DIM_MEMBER via FK so a record in DIM_MEMBER can be

```
ID   Person_dim_id  Member_dim_id
1    123            100
2    123            200
```

Which will allow you to have a one-many membership ID's to a single person. However they can change subscriber ID's without changing member_id or person_ID so i'm wondering if I need to follow the same logic and build a new DIM_SUBSCRIBER table with foreign key for the two previously mentioned tables.

Would this also be the same for all other ID's and each would need a separate dimension table?

The idea is to pull a single person ID and ideally see a history of all data tied to various ID's within the fact tables.

Comment: You allow the user to alter his identifying ID? it is more than strange... Ideally is to use (and hide from everybody) autogenerated, non-changeable unique identifier relative to one person, and refer all records to it.

Comment: Not exactly. If a member moves geolocations, they will be assigned a new member ID. This table was not built with the idea that someone would ever ask for trends across areas like that.